# Prove that the $7$-th cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ contains $\sqrt{-7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Prove that the $7$-th cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ contains $\sqrt{-7}$

I thought that the definition of the $n$-th cyclotomic extension was: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)=\{\mathbb{Q}, \sqrt{-n}\}$. Is this correct?

How could I prove the statement? Could we consider the polynomial $X^2+7$ (which is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion with $p=7$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ if $p \equiv 1$ $(4)$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ if $p \equiv 3$ $(4)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/unique-quadratic-subfield-of-mathbbq-zeta-p-is-mathbbq-sqrtp-if)

Comment: @DietrichBurde The question to which you link subsumes the case here, but there is a somewhat simpler proof in this particular case (as I've provided below)...

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Yes, there is a simpler proof. Like having a proof that the sum of the first odd numbers is a square, and you provide an easier proof that $1+3+5+7=16$ is a square. Still I think, the linked duplicate is the right way to consider this question. Also, there was the confusion of the OP about adjoining $\sqrt{-n}$ instead of $\zeta_n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Perhaps for some; however, the top answer to which you link involves recalling that "only $p$ can ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$" ... the other answers involve a quadratic Gauss sum, and the Vandermonde determinant. I guess from the OP's question here around Eisenstein's criterion as an approach that the more general case involves un-encountered terms. That is, the "right way to consider the question" is a function of the considerer...

Comment: Yes, I agree that one can take this point of view. The other answers here, however, are not too difficult, and still are in the direction of the duplicate. So, I think, it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\alpha = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^{2} + \zeta_7^{4} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.

What is $\alpha$? Well, [**observe**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%282pi*i%2F7%29+%2B+e%5E%284pi*i%2F7%29%2B+e%5E%288pi*i%2F7%29%29%5E2+%2B+%28e%5E%282pi*i%2F7%29+%2B+e%5E%284pi*i%2F7%29%2B+e%5E%288pi*i%2F7%29%29+%2B+2) $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 2 = 0$.

By the quadratic equation, we find:

$$\alpha = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-7}}{2}$$

whence $\sqrt{-7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ as desired. **QED**.

(In particular, the $\pm$ [**should be**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28e%5E%282pi*i%2F7%29+%2B+e%5E%284pi*i%2F7%29%2B+e%5E%288pi*i%2F7%29%29+%2B+1) $+$ although either case yields $\sqrt{-7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ as desired.)

Comment: (cf. **Example 3.0.8** in paul garrett's [**notes**](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/19.pdf).)

Comment: Good. Efficient and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to observe this, but here's one possible way:

1. First, show that the extension is Galois (not too hard) and that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\mathbb{Q})\cong Z_6$. This has subgroups of order 2 and 3.
2. Now find the fixed field of the subgroup of order 3. This is a degree 2 extension. To find the generator, find a generator of the Galois group and write the subgroup in terms of powers of the generator, and find a generator of the subgroup. Look at the orbit of the generator of that subgroup on $\zeta_7$. We guess that this will generate a degree 2 extension.
3. To show that, take powers of that generator and try to find the minimal polynomial. It should be degree 2. The discriminant of the quadratic will be $\sqrt{-7}$, and you will be done.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is defined by adjoining a primitive $n$-th root of unity, and we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n)$.
In particular, it is different from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ for $n>3$. However, every cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ for $p$ prime contains a unique quadratic subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ when $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, or respectively $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ when $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/unique-quadratic-subfield-of-mathbbq-zeta-p-is-mathbbq-sqrtp-if). Since $7\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ the claim follows, i.e., we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)$ is a totally ramified extension above $(7)$ of $\Bbb Z$ with discriminant a power of $7$. But then all subextensions must be totally ramified at $(7)$ and nowhere else. This means their discriminants must divide $7^n$. Because $\phi(7)=6$ is even and the Galois group is cyclic, we know there is a **unique** quadratic subfield, all of which are of the form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{D})$ for some $D$ square free, and we know the discriminant of this field is

$$\begin{cases} D & D\equiv 1\mod 4 \\ 4D & D\equiv 2,3\mod 4\end{cases}$$

So our $D$ must be $\pm 7$, but $+7\equiv 3\mod 4$ would be ramified at $2$, hence it must be that $D=-7\equiv 1\mod 4$.

---

**Addendum** The definition of the $n^{th}$ cyclotomic field is the splitting field of $x^n-1$, your definition would be the splitting field of $x^2+n$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "then all subextensions must be totally ramified at $(7)$ and nowhere else." ? I'm not sure to know why this is true.

Comment: @Watson this is standard ramification theory, see for example Marcus' *Number Fields* or anything about "decomposition," "inertia," and "ramification"  fields of an arbitrary extension, then restrict to the special case of a totally ramified extension.

Answer (score 0):

The method for showing that CZ7 (the cyclotomic numbers on the heptagon, satisfying $x^7+1=0$ and the span of powers of x) contains the $\sqrt{-7}$ is to realise that it is a sixth-order system, and one can dissect an order-two unit by merging the order-3 units out of it, for example, cis2/14 + cis 4/14 + cis 8/14 is invariant to the heptagonal isomorphism, and contains a form in the type x+y sqrt(-7), where these are integers or integer-halfs.

Z7 represents the span of chords of the heptagon.  CZ7 represents the cyclotomic numbers form by dividing the half-circle into seven parts, and taking the span over Z.  This represents the verticies of the tiling {7, 14/5}.  It has a construction in terms of a general carryless base, modulo by setting a polynomial to zero, as $Pm(x^7+1=0)$.  $P$ here represents $\sum z_j x^j$, where z,j are in the integers Z and $m(\mbox{eqn})$ represents an equity equation.

Some elementry number theory can prove that if $p$ is a prime of the form $4x+3$, then the cyclotomic numbers CZp contain $Z(1, \frac 12(1+\sqrt{-p}))$.

The rule of isomorphism says that there are several solutions to this equation, and putting eg x + x' + x" = y gives a value automorphic to this value.  In the case of CZ7, an automorphic solution can be had by replacing $x$ by $x^9$ by $x^{11}$ by $x$.  So the triplets $x+x^9+x^{11}$, and $x^2+x^4+x^8$ etc, are automorphic to the $x$ -> $x^9$ transform.

Comment: I've added more to the answer.